# Simple string regular expression

Tags: c#, regex

I'm trying to write very simple regular expression - this world is entirely new for me so I need an help.

I need to validate the next pattern: starts with C0 and finish with 4 digits exactly for example:

```
C01245 - legal

C04751 - legal

C15821 - not legal (does not starts with 'C0')

C0412 - not legal (mismatch length)

C0a457 - not legal
```

I took "cheat sheet" and wrote the next pattern:

C0\A\d{4) which means (I think) : starts with C0 and continue with 4 digits but this pattern always return "false".

What wrong with my pattern?

Comment: `C0[0-9]{4}` this should work.

Comment: I see two ways of reading your description of the problem, and your examples are not consistent with either of them.  Either you want precisely `C0####`, in which case none of your examples should pass, or you want `C0--whatever you like here--####`, which which case `C0**a**4587` should pass.  Is there somewhere I'm confused?

Comment: instead of d{4) it should be d{4} .^ palce at the start.:::> ^C0\d{4}$

Comment: I think it clear enough. I want C0 and than 4 digits [0-9].

Comment: Then why does `C047851` pass?  That's C0, followed by 5 digits

Comment: Ohh you right - sorry I will fix it immediately

Comment: C012345 --> C0 then 12345 -> this look 5 digit after C0 for me, not **finish with 4 digits exactly** :D and you can use `C0\d{5}`. Or `^(C0\d{5})$` if and only if the string just formed by those 7 character

Comment: Is `C0a1234` or `C012345678` legal? You said it had to finish w/ 4 digits, but you didn't say anything about stuff being inside or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use this regex

```
^C0\d{4}$
```

`^` would mark the beginning of string

`$` would mark the end of string

`\d{4}` would match  4 digits

---

You could also do it this way

```
if(input.StartsWith("C0") &&
   input.Length==6 && 
   input.Substring(2).ToCharArray().All(x=>Char.IsDigit(x)))
//valid
else //invalid
```

Comment: This problem is a perfect example of a need for a regular expression. I see no reason to even consider the alternative method here.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried your your suggestion and it seems fine. Is there any preferable regular expression between your one to the next one: \AC0\d{4}\Z

Comment: @sfjedi what's wrong with the string manipulations? seems good to me :/

Comment: @Mr_Green It's just really verbose.

Answer (score 1):

```
^C0\d{4,}$
```

The string must start `^` with `C0`, followed by 4 or more digits `\d{4,}` at the end of the string `$`.

Simply take off the last `$` if it's not actually at the end of the string.

And if you're not looking to sandwich more numbers in-between, just remove the comma..

Kudos to @femtoRgon for the `\d{4,}` (see comments).

Comment: Fun fact: I believe `\d*\d{4}` could be replaced with `\d{4,}`.

Comment: and this can be more shortened to `^C0\d*$`. right? if assumed the digits after `C0` are `4`.

Comment: @Mr_Green No, because he said it requires exactly 4 digits at the end.

Comment: I am saying what is the reason to consider `{4, }` on first place. when the OP require exactly 4 digits. (just trying to know)

Comment: @Mr_Green it's the way he worded it. He said it had to start with `C0` and end with exactly 4 digits, but he didn't say anything about digits in-between being invalid or not.

Comment: @Mr_Green and there's no space after the comma. It's just `{4,}` as @femtoRgon originally suggested.

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at this Snippet ,

```
using System.IO;
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        string input1 = "C0123456"; 
        // input1 starts with C0 and ends with 4 digit , allowing any number of                 
        // characters/digit in between
        string input2 = "C01234";
        // input2 starts with C0 and ends with 4 digit , without                
        // characters/digit in between
        String pattern1=@"\b[C][0][a-z A-Z 0-9]*\d{4}\b";
        String pattern2=@"\b[C][0]\d{4}\b";
        Match m = Regex.Match(input1, pattern1);
        if(m.Success)
        Console.WriteLine("Pattern1 matched input1 and the value is : "+m.Value);
        m = Regex.Match(input2, pattern2);
        if(m.Success)
        Console.WriteLine("Pattern2 matched input2 and the value is : "+m.Value);
          m = Regex.Match(input1, pattern2);
        if(m.Success)
        Console.WriteLine("Pattern2 matched input1 and the value is : "+m.Value);
          m = Regex.Match(input2, pattern1);
        if(m.Success)
        Console.WriteLine("Pattern1 matched input2 and the value is : "+m.Value);


    }
}
```

Output:

Pattern1 matched input1 and the value is : C0123456

Pattern2 matched input2 and the value is : C01234

Pattern1 matched input2 and the value is : C01234

Answer (score -1):

if you go to http://gskinner.com/RegExr/ you can write this expression:

```
^(C0[0-9]*[0-9]{4})[^0-9]
```

And in the content you put:

```
C012345 - legal
C047851 - legal
C*1*54821 - not legal (does not starts with 'C0')
C0412 - not legal (mismatch length)
C0*a*4587 - not legal
```

And you will see that it only matches what you want.

Comment: `[0-9]` can be replaced with `\d`

Comment: This isn't necessarily a good idea, [0-9] is a faster match pattern, and also excludes all unicode-defined digits (if we're not trying to match on these, which the OP is proposing).

Comment: We can use `\d` or `[0-9]`. both are same.

Comment: @Mr_Green yeah but, again, why would we choose the more verbose way in this case? `\d` is there for a reason. Why not use it? 5 characters vs. 2.

Comment: I am used to write it as [0-9] in java because I have to double backslash when I want to use it like this \\d, and so the longer version is for me more readable. But is new and interesting to me the comment from @Sparko

Comment: @sfjedi haha.. that depends on individuals I suppose. :). Honestly, I always use `[0-9]`.

Comment: @Sparko are you sure this is the way it works? I just did a jsperf and the results seem inconclusive. That is, there doesn't seem to be a consistent difference between one or the other in terms of performance. See the test here: http://jsperf.com/regex-0-9-vs-d

Comment: @DavidHofmann and since this post is about C#, you can just precede the string with `@` and type `\d` without any additional slashes. Not sure if Java has a similar thing.

Comment: @Sparko, sorry but those micro-benchmarks doesn't tell much. It depends on many things like jvm warmed up and the lenght of your string